# github what is origin in git remote add origin

Tags: git, github

in a previous post I tried to use git remote add [origin] mygithubUrl/reop
my question now is  what to replace [origin] with? is it my local repo?
I have tried many things but I get errors of all kinds; the irony is i have done this before !

my last attempt:
I cloned  github repo  into my desktop and then copy and pasted messageboards project and then tried git push -u origin.....then user name /password
and i get error  failed to push some refs..
hint: updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you have not have locally;this usually caused by another repo pushing to the same ref
you may first want to integrate the remote changes  e.g. git pull.......

Answer (score 0):

*Origin* is a remote. It is the default remote that git creates for you when you do the initial clone. The [origin] you're seeing is just saying that you should supply some name for the remote that you're adding. It can be anything you want.

The syntax for adding a remote is:

`git remote add [shortname] [url]`

Where [shortname] is just some name for you to easily reference the remote, and [url] is of course the url of the remote repository.